# Pandas sort_values gives unexpected results

Tags: pandas, sorting

I am having trouble seeing why the sort order differs between the two sort_by commands. The example is taken directly from my data. According to the docs, sort_values should sort by the specified axis (default axis=0) and the specified (by=) index/column(s).

The way I see it, both sort_values commands should give the same results, since the only differences are the 1st and last character which are the same for every value in the specified column.

```
import pandas as pd

dc=[['@10309000_0010@','!10309000_0010!'],
      ['@10309000_0011@','!10309000_0011!'],
      ['@10309000_0012@','!10309000_0012!'],
      ['@10309000_00@','!10309000_00!']]
df=pd.DataFrame(dc,columns=['c1','c2'])
df
```

Data:

```
                 c1              c2
0   @10309000_0010@ !10309000_0010!
1   @10309000_0011@ !10309000_0011!
2   @10309000_0012@ !10309000_0012!
3   @10309000_00@   !10309000_00!
```

Sort by columns c1:

```
df.sort_values(by='c1')
```

Resutls, sample 10309000_0010 is first:

```
                 c1              c2
0   @10309000_0010@ !10309000_0010!
1   @10309000_0011@ !10309000_0011!
2   @10309000_0012@ !10309000_0012!
3   @10309000_00@   !10309000_00!
```

Sort by column c2:

```
df.sort_values(by='c2')
```

Results, sample 10309000_00 is now first:

```
                 c1              c2
3   @10309000_00@   !10309000_00!
0   @10309000_0010@ !10309000_0010!
1   @10309000_0011@ !10309000_0011!
2   @10309000_0012@ !10309000_0012!
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a general effect of how strings work: every character [corresponds to a numeric value](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange).

```
>>> {ch: ord(ch) for ch in '1!@'}
{'1': 49, '!': 33, '@': 64}
```

When sorting, the numeric value determines the ordering. As a result of `64 > 49 > 33` it also holds that `'@' > '1' > '!'`.

Note that the *character* `'1'` does not have the ordering `1`. The string is different from the number it represents. Likewise, the string `"@10309000_0010@"` is not ordered as "number enclosed by `@`" but "string of characters `'@'`, `1`, `0`, ...". Strings are compared using [lexicographic ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) - this is similar to how `tuple`s are compared. The important part is that this compares from the *leading positions*, with trailing positions ignored after a mismatch:

```
>>> "2" > "3"   # 2 > 3 decides comparison
False
>>> "2" > "1"   # 2 > 1 decides comparison
True
>>> "2" > "10"  # 2 > 1 decides comparison
True
```

If you compare `"@10309000_0012@"` against `"@10309000_00@"`, then the difference at position 12 of `'1'` versus `'@'` decides the match. The trailing `"2@"` if the longer string is not inspected. The same applies when replacing `'@'` with `'!'`. In other words, it boils down to `'@' > '1' > '!'`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the relative precedence of !>1>@. So sorting by c1 puts everything with a '1' in [12] ahead of everything with '@' in [12], but sorting by c2 puts everything with a '!' in [12] ahead of everything with '1' in [12], which indirectly gives me the answer I want.

```
s=pd.Series(['@','1','!'])

2    !
1    1
0    @
```

I think natsort maybe more robust.

(Sorry for the late night confusion and thanks again anky_91.)

Comment: No it isn't. You failed to clearly explain the behavior was due to the relative importance of !>1>@. You simply showed !>@. I asked you to clarify so I could upvote your contribution, but you deleted your answer. I'm happy to give you credit for helping me understand it, this isn't the first time you've helped me. I just didn't think your answer made it quite clear enough.

Comment: No, i explained about `!1>@1` not `!>@` . but fair enough. whatever you think best explains :)